# What needs to be increased and howmuch - SharePoint 2010?

Tags: performance, memory-leak

1. Less than 5 percent of RAM is available or less than 64 MB of RAM is
   available
2. More than 70% the Commit Limit is in use
3. Greater than 15ms physical disk READ response times
4. Less than 500 MB of free disk space ("LogicalDisk(HarddiskVolume1)\Free Megabytes")
5. The working  set of all processes combined is increasing at a rate greater than
   100 MB per hour
6. SharePoint's publishing cache hit ratio is less then 99 percent
7. Possible Handle Leak: More than 500 handles between overall Min and overall Max and an increasing trend of more than 500 handles per hour

Based on the above report, what needs to be increased and howmuch - SharePoint 2010?

Server Configuration:
2 - WFEs - 2k8 R2 - 4GB of RAM, 2 X 2.4Ghz Processor.
2 - AppServer - 2k8 R2 - 4GB of RAM, 2 X 2.4Ghz Processor.

Comment: You need more RAM, more harddrive, and you seem to have a memoryleak in your code

Comment: how to I find how much I may need?

Comment: You can't really, since when the server runs out of memory and disk it shuts down services and starts doing stuff really slow, all you can do is add more until it stabilizes below the thresholds! But a rising memory on a web front end running 2010 is almost always caused by code not properly disposing com objects

Comment: Just to add a bit to Roberts comments, you need to identify all custom components that are in the farm. Web parts, event handlers, etc. and identify how much system resources they are using. Your troubles could just come from some poorly written custom code.

Comment: Do you mean I may have to use the SPDispose Check util to find the system resources utilization? I dont have the source code for few of the custom solutions.